# Firefox is extremely slow / not working in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, firefox

I have two VMs on an internal network (using VirtualBox), one of them is running Kali Linux, the other one is a vulnerable machine. I am trying to solve some vulnhub problems.
I have found out the IP of the vulnerable machine, but Firefox is not working on Kali Linux, when I entered the IP nothing happens. It is extremely slow. 
Is there any workaround or should it be a configuration issue? Do you need any details to answer? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 11):

Okay, got that. Here is the fix:
Put "about:config" into the browser
in the search field enter: "browser.tabs.remote.autostart" and set its value to False. 
Restart the browser. 
It worked for me, if someone struggles with the same...

Comment: Thank you - in my case, I couldn't even get a web page to load. Changing this fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 10 as host, then:

1. Try going to Control Panel -> System and Security -> Security and Maintenance.
2. Then click on Network Firewall (view in windows security)
3. Then click on the the network you are using and (btn domain, public and private)
4. Then click on Allow App Through Firewall and add your virtual machine (in this case virtualbox) to the list.

That's it.